# Get a "train or test" slicing elegantly after splitting

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am learning numpy, pandas, and sklearn for machine learning now. My teacher gives me code like below, but I guess it is ugly. This code is for splitting the data into training set and testing set, and later we could manipulate the entire data or just training/testing set by the `[True, False, True, False ... ]` `idx_train`/`idx_test` list later.

> ```
> import numpy as np
> import pandas as pd
> from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
>
> m = 10
> x1 = np.arange(m)
> x2 = x1 * 2
> x3 = x1 * 3
> x4 = x1 * 4
> x = np.c_[x1, x2, x3, x4]
> x = pd.DataFrame(x)
>
> x_train, x_test = train_test_split(x, train_size=0.7, random_state=666)
> TRAIN, TEST = 'train', 'test'
> TRAIN_TEST = TRAIN + TEST
> pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
> x_train[TRAIN_TEST] = TRAIN
> x_test[TRAIN_TEST] = TEST
> pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'warn'
> x = pd.concat([x_train, x_test])
> idx_train = x[TRAIN_TEST] == TRAIN
> idx_test = np.invert(idx_train)
> x_train = x[idx_train]  # later
> x_test = x[idx_test]
> ```

And I get the below code by myself. I feel it is only a little better.

```
offset_orig = np.arange(m)
rate = 0.7
offset_train, offset_test = train_test_split(offset_orig, train_size=rate, random_state=666)
if rate < 0.5:
    offset_set_train = set(offset_train)
    idx_train = [i in offset_set_train for i in offset_orig]  # This may be slow. Is numpy broadcast or implicit cycling available here?
    idx_test = np.invert(idx_train)
else:
    offset_set_test = set(offset_test)
    idx_test = [i in offset_set_test for i in offset_orig]  # This may be slow. Is numpy broadcast or implicit cycling available here?
    idx_train = np.invert(idx_test)

x_train = x[idx_train]  # later
x_test = x[idx_test]
```

I want to get the `[True, False, True, False ... ]` list `idx_train` and `idx_test` for slicing usage later.

I believe that in the world of Python, there should be and will be only one appropriate way to achieve an objective. Could someone give me that very approach to get a "train or test" slicing? (Usage of the lib function `train_test_split` is required.)

Comment: [Cross-posted at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67671132/1014587)

Comment: Sorry, I am suggested to post my question here. The original post in StackOverflow has some information entered by other users, and I feel it should not be deleted.

Comment: @Mast The cross post was removed by moderators on SO. Is this still a good question or can it be closed/removed.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I see no reason to close it.

Answer (score 2):

**Inspired by Gulzar at Stackoverflow.**

I do not realize it works until after a night's sleep.

**So, below is enough:**

```python
offset_orig = range(m)
offset_train, offset_test = train_test_split(offset_orig, train_size=0.7, random_state=666)

x_train = x.iloc[offset_train]  # later
x_test = x.iloc[offset_test]
```

**The `offset_train` list (`[0, 2, ...]`) has the same feature in later programming against the `[True, False, True, False ...]` list for slicing I pursued at the beginning.**

For example, I can use offset_train later as below:

> ```python
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import seaborn as sns
> fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
> fig.set_size_inches(12, 10)
> sns.boxplot(data=df.iloc[offset_train], y='count', ax=axes[0][0])
> sns.boxplot(data=df.iloc[offset_train], y='count', x='season', ax=axes[0][1])
> sns.boxplot(data=df.iloc[offset_train], y='count', x='hour', ax=axes[1][0])
> sns.boxplot(data=df.iloc[offset_train], y='count', x='workingday', ax=axes[1][1])
> ```

And even as below:

> ```python
> # get noise index
> mu_count = df.loc[offset_train, 'count'].mean(axis=0)
> sigma_count = df.loc[offset_train, 'count'].std(axis=0)
> idx_bad_np = abs(df.loc[offset_train, 'count'] - mu_count) > 3 * sigma_count
> idx_good_np = np.invert(idx_bad_np)
> # remove noise index
> print(f'Before removal: sum(idx good) = {sum(idx_good_np)}, sum(idx bad) = {sum(idx_bad_np)}, len(df[train]) = {len(df.iloc[offset_train])}')
> offset_train = list(set(offset_train) - set(np.array(offset_train)[idx_bad_np]))
> print(f'After removal: sum(idx good) = {sum(idx_good_np)}, sum(idx bad) = {sum(idx_bad_np)}, len(df[train]) = {len(df.iloc[offset_train])}')
> # check again
> idx_bad_np = abs(df.loc[offset_train, 'count'] - mu_count) > 3 * sigma_count
> print(f'Check sum(idx bad) after removal: {sum(idx_bad_np)}')
> ```

Thanks to the community. I feel I have so far to go on the path of Python.